# My images are not loading in my site in both github pages and netlify

Tags: html, css, github-pages, netlify

So I made a static site and it is working fine in my machine, but when I host it either with netlify or github pages it shows no images. Here is my github public repository link : https://github.com/Omar-Gebal/Hosting-static-site and here is my site on netlify : https://hosting-site-static.netlify.app/ . and here is my html code linking the images

```html
 <nav class="zone black sticky">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our team</a></li>
        <li class="push"><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container zone">
      <img src="/Hosting-static-site/Asset 28.png" alt="" class="cover" />
      <h1>Own the internet. Start with fast web hosting.</h1>
      <button>Learn more</button>
    </div>
    <div class="zone dark-blue grid-wrapper">
      <div class="box zone">
        <img src="/Hosting-static-site/data_storage_2_2.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="box zone">
        <img src="/Hosting-static-site/files_2.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="box zone">
        <img src="/Hosting-static-site/desktop_analytics_2.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="box zone">
        <img src="/Hosting-static-site/monitor_coding_2.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="box zone">
        <img src="/Hosting-static-site/monitor_settings_2.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="box zone">
        <img src="/Hosting-static-site/server_2_2.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="box zone">
        <img src="/Hosting-static-site/server_3.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="box zone">
        <img src="/Hosting-static-site/server_safe_2.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: put a . in front of the first slash. Like this --> `./`

Comment: Are the images that you are referring to in the exact same directory on the server as your local machine? As @EvikGhazarian said, adding the . before the / will make it go to the current directory instead of the root one, which is most certainly different.

Comment: @EvikGhazarian Didn't work it made the local version not show images too

Comment: @majneeds2chill Did it like that and didn't work  
      eg. <img src="./Hosting-static-site/Asset 28.png" alt="" class="cover" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image path is supposed to be different. Right now you have it under a folder, but on the repo they are not in the folder.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. visual studio code added that folder for whatever reason but now it's fixed. my badd.